# Help for misconfiguration on WP-Config: not able to set it back to WP Standard

Tags: wp-config

On an installation of WordPress, I saw the previous programmer have made a mod, moving some folder outside the standard directories.

The settings I found in `wp-config.php` are here below:

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'engine');
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME) ;
define ('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . '/'. WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
define ('WP_PLUGIN_FOLDERNAME', 'plugins');
define ('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_PLUGIN_FOLDERNAME);
define ('WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_SITEURL . '/' . WP_PLUGIN_FOLDERNAME);
define ('UPLOADS', 'files');
```

I wanted to set WordPress back to the standard files/folders structure, so that I commented the above lines after I have moved the folders and files where they have to be (into the directory /wp-content) and after have made the backup of the database.

What I got is that WordPress finds the plugins (now moved into the correct folder: `wp-content/plugins`) but not any longer the files (pictures, MP3s) that are located into the folder `wp-content/files` and that they should populate the MEDIA menu into the wordpress dashboard. Into the MEDIA menu, there are the file names but in the reality all files are not addressed any longer.

Due the above lines, previously these files were located into the folder `<domainname>/engine/files` instead of `<domainname>/wp-content/files`.

Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within some plugin that stored the full path into the database. I solved just adding a redirection line into the .htaccess so that any call to that specific address was redirecting to `wp-content/uploads` isntad to `files`